# i have query that inserting values into MySQL database with array and for loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have query that inserting values into MySQL database with array and for loop.but when i submit form  MySQL database showing double entry. First Record is empty and Second Record is with values? Why MySQL database showing First Record Empty Entry.i don't know what is reason behind it?

**HERE My Function Code**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['order'])) 
{
$count=1;
$count++;   
$total=$_POST['total']; 
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
$queryproduct=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shoppingcart VALUES    ('','','','$uid','$email','".$_POST['product'][$i]."','".$_POST['userfile_name'] [$i]."','".$_POST['price'][$i]."','".$_POST['qty'][$i]."','".$_POST['amt'][$i]."','$total')") or die("Order  Query Problem");    
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Avoid using the dated `mysql_*` functions. Using them for new code is [highly discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query). More modern alternatives are available and better maintained. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) via either [PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @MattBall mysql_query is not recommended??

Comment: Why are you setting $count = 1 and then increase it by 1? Also, try instead of inserting '' the statement `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2,...)`

Comment: @Voitcus i need to use them in different pages.. that's why

Comment: @FarhanDharsi Correct, `mysql_query()` is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your loop from 0, as the $_POST["pid"] variable is numbered from 0, as in second (working) example:

```
for($i=0; $i<$lenght; $i++){ ...
```

However, avoid using mysql_* functions as Matt Ball stated in his comment.

Comment: sorry brother next time i will use matt ball method

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the security problems with this code first off, we can come back to that part later. Let's first deal with the problem that I'm seeing right way.

> First Record is empty and Second Record is with values? Why MySQL database showing First Record Empty Entry.i don't know what is reason behind it?

```
$count=1;
$count++;
```

What is going on here? Your setting a `$count` equal to `1` and then your immediately incrementing it by one too `2` on the second line. Why are you doing that? Why not set it too two in the first place?

I would bet, that you're problem with the First Record being Empty starts right with those lines of code.

```
$total = $_POST['total'];
```

This is only used in the query once, so why assign it to another variable at all you are just wasting memory.

From the first example of your code, I would say that this would be the best execution you could get from it (again, not talking about security).

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['order'])) 
{
    for ($i = 1, $count = 0; $i <= $count; ++$i)
    {
        $queryproduct = mysql_query
        (
            "INSERT INTO shoppingcart VALUES
            (
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '$uid',
                '$email',
                '{$_POST['product'][$i]}',
                '{$_POST['userfile_name'][$i]}',
                '{$_POST['price'][$i]}',
                '{$_POST['qty'][$i]}',
                '{$_POST['amt'][$i]}',
                '{$_POST['total']}'
            );"
        )
        or die("Order Query Problem");
    }
}
?>
```

---

Looking at your second set of code, this would probably be the best you could do with it.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['order']))
    {
        for($i = 0, $p = count($_POST['product']); $i < $p; ++$i)
        {
            $queryproduct = mysql_query
            (
                "INSERT INTO shoppingcart VALUES
                (
                    '',
                    '',
                    '{$_POST['pid'][$i]}',
                    '$uid',
                    '$email',
                    '{$_POST['product'][$i]}',
                    '{$_POST['userfile_name'][$i]}',
                    '{$_POST['price'][$i]}',
                    '{$_POST['qty'][$i]}',
                    '{$_POST['amt'][$i]}',
                    '{$_POST['total']}'
                );"
            )
            or die("Order Query Problem");
        }
    }
?>
```

---

Finally, and this one is about security. We could make these statements safe if we used some of the non-deprecated functions found within the PHP Code Base.

PDO is the most common of these interfaces, and you can find [all of the documentation you need](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to setup a PDO connection to your SQL Database.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['order']))
    {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO shoppingcart VALUES ('', '', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $pid);

        $stmt->bindParam(2, $uid);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $email);

        $stmt->bindParam(4, $product);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(6, $price);
        $stmt->bindParam(7, $qty);
        $stmt->bindParam(8, $amt);

        $stmt->bindParam(9, $total);

        for($i = 0, $p = count($_POST['product']); $i < $p; ++$i)
        {
            $pid = $_POST['pid'][$i]);

            $product = $_POST['product'][$i]);
            $name = $_POST['userfile_name'][$i]);
            $price = $_POST['price'][$i]);
            $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i]);
            $amt = $_POST['amt'][$i]);

            $total = $_POST['total'];
        }

        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

These will take care of correctly escaping query statements for you. A massive help, when we all can't know every attack vector and the experts have already come up with code on how to fix the most common ones.